# can't connect java ee spring project to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm unable to connect to `mysql` even though I added the connector jar files in both referenced libraries and jre system.

Here is the error when I try to ping `MYSQL`.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:798)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.internalCreateConnection(JDBCConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Are you sure you added the jar files in the right place? Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path

In Libraries Tab press Add External Jar and Select your jar.

Comment: @Sterls Project build path doesn't affect `datatools`.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse DataTools are not associated with any particular Eclipse Project, so adding the JDBC jar file to the classpath of a Project doesn't help.

You need to configure the DataTools Driver Definition.

In Eclipse, right-click the Database Connection. This is where you can also find the `Ping` I believe you're talking about. Select `Properties`.

Select `Xxx Properties` on the left. You should see a `Drivers` combobox with the MySQL driver already selected. Click the `Edit Driver Definition` icon to the right of the combobox (looks like a triangle). Select the `JAR List` tab and add/edit/fix the location of the JDBC driver jar file.

Alternatively, go to `Preferences` > `Data Management` > `Connectivity` > `Driver Definition`.